# Ionic native contacts cordova plugin deprecated? Any alternatives?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, native, contacts

I have read that the [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/)
has been deprecated. What solutions are there to find a list of the contacts on the device? I want to have the 'allow contacts' modal to pop open click 'allow' then get the contacts array from device.

So far I found how to implement the plugin only to have my app crash when calling the function. Seems like it wont work because the plugin is deprecated (no longer supported).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the source of your problem is not that. Yes the plugin is deprecated but that does not mean it does not work. I'm still using it on one of my projects and it works fine. You should paste your code so we can see what the problem is.